# Fill an triangle over a 3D Numpy array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, mesh, fill

I have an array defined as:

```
    arrayXYZ=np.full((1000,1200,1500),np.uint8(0))
```

I want to fill triangles inside that array with the value "np.uint8(255)".

Each triangle is defined with 3 3D integer vertex points (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3) each.

I want to have that arrayXYZ in memory and not displayed.

How to do that the best way and fast enough?

Thanks,

Luis Gonçalves

Comment: a filled triangle?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "filling an array with triangles". Does the array represent some geometrical structure? You'll have to rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes, a filled 2D triangle, inside filled (with 3D coordinates, triangle 2.5D, I suppose)  in a 3D array (arrayXYZ).

Comment: Yes, the group of triangles is a picture (surface) and the triangles are a mesh. But I want to do for that array arrayXYZ instead to the screen.